# Numpy: Comparing two data sets for fitness

Tags: python, numpy, data-fitting

I'm drawing a blank on this.

I have two data sets:

```
d1 = [(x1,y1), (x2,y2)...] 
d2 = [(x1,y1), (x2,y2)...]
```

I would like to get some type of statistical value, maybe something like an r-value, that tells me how well `d2` fits to `d1`.

Comment: It is not clear what statistical value you expect. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/73805 for details

Comment: My first thought would be reduced chi-squared.  It depends on how you got the two sets.  You might want to look at [Goodness of fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit).

Answer (score 2):

It dependents on what are those two vectors. you may want to be more specific.

If they are something like X-Y coordinates in Cartesian system, distance correlation is probably the most appropriate (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation#Alternative_formulation:_Brownian_covariance).

If the `x` values are the same and `d1` has the expected `y` under each `x` values based on a certain model (i.e. a linear model) and `d2` has the observed `y` values, then Pearson's r may be a good choose `scipy.stats.pearsonr` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient).

If both `d1` and `d2` are relative frequency data (observed `y` count of events of value `x`), then some type of goodness of fit test may be the right direction to go. `scipy.stats.chisquare`, `scipy.stats.chi2_contingency`, `scipy.stats.ks_2samp`, to name a few.